# No unicoded Font-Awesome Icon on Tablet ( ios & android )

Tags: android, ios, css, font-awesome

i defined a css-class, that prepends a font-awesome icon with ":before" to a li-element. I use this class within a text-editor for styling lists.
So far so good - On Desktop ( in several Browsers ) this will do fine, but an ios and andriod devices it shows me only a square.
The other implemented Font-Awesome--Tags work fine on all devices.
Do somebody know what i do wrong?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide pls. a fiddle so that we could view in on iOS-Devices?

Comment: you can see it here http://www.smartproject.de/erster-schritt/

Answer (score 0):

The .CSS on your site says that you are using FontAwesome 5. With FA5, you should be using a tag like "`fas fa-phone`", but you did "`fa fa-phone`" which is used for FA4. 
So far the theory. Why it displays correctly on PC and not on iOS is puzzling, but I have verified that the [phone-icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/phone?style=solid) displays correctly on iOS when using the modified tags.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, MBaas...but i'm not using the classes in this case. I use it within a css-rule like

```css
li::before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: "\f00c";
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: inherit;
   margin-right: 0.5em;
   color: #355eab;
   }
```